# Best way to loop through this array to display grouped Angular/html elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I am working with an API that returns payment options for a service. The payment options are (1 yr of the service, paid in monthly increments), (1 yr of service, upfront), (2 yr of service, paid in monthly increments), (2 yr of service, upfront). The data gets returned in the following way:

```
options = [
  { price: 10,
    serviceLength: "1 year",
    paymentFrequency: "monthly payment",
  },
  { price: 100,
    serviceLength: "1 year",
    paymentFrequency: "one-time payment",
  },
  { price: 8,
    serviceLength: "2 year",
    paymentFrequency: "monthly payment",
  },
  { price: 150,
    serviceLength: "2 year",
    paymentFrequency: "one-time payment",
  },
]
```

I need to display the data in a way that groups the 1 yr service options together and the 2 yr service options together. Something like this:

1 Year Service

- Monthly - $XX.XX
- Upfront: $XX.XX

2 Year Service

- Monthly - $XX.XX
- Upfront: $XX.XX

What is the best way to organize the data to do this? More price options are likely to be added in the future. I was thinking of having a function to separate out the year lengths and then have a double for loop to display the options?

Something like:

```
oneYearOptions = [
  { price: 10,
    serviceLength: "1 year",
    paymentFrequency: "monthly payment",
  },
  { price: 100,
    serviceLength: "1 year",
    paymentFrequency: "one-time payment",
  },

twoYearOptions = [
  { price: 8,
    serviceLength: "2 year",
    paymentFrequency: "monthly payment",
  },
  { price: 150,
    serviceLength: "2 year",
    paymentFrequency: "one-time payment",
  },
];

const allOptions = [oneYearOptions, twoYearOptions];
```

and then the angular ts would be something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let option of allOptions>
   <div *ngFor="let priceOption of priceOptions">
     {{ list the data in here }}
   </div>
</div>
```

This just feels inefficient to me. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe to use a hashmap instead?

Comment: Frankly, this seems like a reasonable way to get it done considering that you have no control over the API return data format. You might be able to save on some memory by not having to split the array into multiple arrays but I don't think there's really any need to do that. As for speed performance, you're going to have to loop over each item and display it regardless so you can't do better than "loop over each item".

Comment: If you can change the data you could do it in a single loop if you’d prefer. You can have an array with objects where objects can have a type like ‘header’ or options (where option is the object you have now).

Answer (score 0):

just an object that has as property "options" that is an array

```
options =  
    {serviceLength: "1 year",
     options:[
      { price: 10,
       paymentFrequency: "monthly payment",
      },
      { price: 100,
       paymentFrequency: "one-time payment",
      }]
    },
    { serviceLength: "2 year",
      options:[
      { price: 8,
        paymentFrequency: "monthly payment",
      },
      { price: 150,
        paymentFrequency: "one-time payment",
      }]
    }
]
```

It's true that if you store the data in a dbs like your first array of object, it's good transform to this another way using reduce

```
this.options=this.data.reduce((a:any,b:any)=>{
    const el=a.find(x=>x.serviceLength==b.serviceLength)
    if (el){
      el.options=[...el.options,{price:b.price,paymentFrequency:b.paymentFrequency}]
      return a;
    }
     return [...a,{serviceLength:b.serviceLength,options:[{price:b.price,paymentFrequency:b.paymentFrequency}]}]
  },[])
```

The .html becomes like

```
<div *ngFor="let option of options">
  <div>{{option.serviceLength}}</div>
  <!--see the inner .html loop over "option.options"-->
  <div *ngFor="let priceOption of option.options">
     {{ priceOption.price}} {{priceOption.paymentFrecuency}}
   </div>
</div>
```

A [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kqywuc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You could also iterate over filtered versions of your array if you don't feel like manipulating the data:

```html
<div *ngFor="let option of options.filter(option => option.serviceLength == '1 year')">
     {{ list the data in here }}
</div>
<div *ngFor="let option of options.filter(option => option.serviceLength == '2 year')">
     {{ list the data in here }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use a groupBy pipe here.

```
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name:"groupBy"
})
export class GroupBy implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any[]) : number {
    return array.reduce((trasnformedOption, { serviceLength })=>{
      if(!trasnformedOption.some(option => option.serviceLength === serviceLength)){
        trasnformedOption.push({
          serviceLength ,
          serviceDetails : array.filter(v=>v.serviceLength === serviceLength)
        });
      }
      return trasnformedOption;
    },[]);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  options = [
    { price: 10,
      serviceLength: "1 year",
      paymentFrequency: "monthly payment",
    },
    { price: 100,
      serviceLength: "1 year",
      paymentFrequency: "one-time payment",
    },
    { price: 8,
      serviceLength: "2 year",
      paymentFrequency: "monthly payment",
    },
    { price: 150,
      serviceLength: "2 year",
      paymentFrequency: "one-time payment",
    },
  ];
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let option of options | groupBy">
    {{ option.serviceLength }}
    <div *ngFor="let details of option.serviceDetails">
      {{ details.paymentFrequency}} - {{ details.price }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```